# Jquery ajax get xml parse error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I want get a XML from this url usin Jquery ajax https://sisa.msal.gov.ar/sisa/services/rest/puco/44003375

Via browser I can see this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<puco>
 <resultado>OK</resultado>
 <coberturaSocial>O.S.P. CIUDAD AUT</coberturaSocial>
<denominacion>AGOSTINO RODRIGO LEONARDO</denominacion>
<nrodoc>44003375</nrodoc>
<rnos>901001</rnos>
<tipodoc>DNI</tipodoc>
</puco>
```

But when doing:

```
var id=44003375;
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url  : 'https://sisa.msal.gov.ar/sisa/services/rest/puco/'+id,
    dataType :"JSONP",
    jsonp: true,
    success : function(xhr){
      alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
    },
    error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
      var clientid = $(httpReq).text();
      alert(JSON.stringify(httpReq));
    }
 });
```

Return "Parse error"... how I can get via ajax what the browser shows?

Comment: XML is not JSON

Comment: Sure, but only that way, reponse url content.  dataType :"xml", "text", "html" reponse nothing

Comment: I'm trying to call the url https://sisa.msal.gov.ar/sisa/services/rest/puco/44003375, the services discontinued by the govt. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved, but with PHP

```
<?php 
  $response = file_get_contents('https://sisa.msal.gov.ar/sisa/services/rest/puco/44003375');
  $response = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
  dd($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  JavaScript `.load()` and then parse the XML to JSON [as detailed here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use any xml to json converter or parser. Have a look at  http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/